# telegraf file output failed to write message

Tags: fileoutputstream, telegraf

This is my `/etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf` file, section `outputs.file`:

```
 [[outputs.file]]

   files = ["stdout", "/home/zeinab/metrics.out"]
   data_format = "influx"
```

But `telegraf` log (which are written in `/var/log/syslog`) shows error continuously:

```
Jan 15 12:14:33 ZiZi telegraf[19916]: kernel,host=ZiZi context_switches=9275452836i,boot_time=1515496651i,processes_forked=1203986i,interrupts=1381624861i 1516005867000000000
Jan 15 12:14:33 ZiZi telegraf[19916]: 2018-01-15T08:44:33Z E! Error writing to output [file]: failed to write message: kernel,host=ZiZi context_switches=9275452836i,boot_time=1515496651i,processes_forked=1203986i,interrupts=1381624861i 1516005867000000000
Jan 15 12:14:33 ZiZi telegraf[19916]: , invalid argument
```

**EDIT 1:**

The whole un-commented configs are:

```
[global_tags]

[agent]
  interval = "10s"
  round_interval = true
  metric_batch_size = 1000
  metric_buffer_limit = 10000
  collection_jitter = "0s"
  flush_interval = "10s"
  flush_jitter = "0s"
  precision = ""
  debug = false
  quiet = false
  logfile = ""
  hostname = ""
  omit_hostname = false

[[outputs.influxdb]]
   urls = ["udp://127.0.0.1:8089"] # UDP endpoint example
  database = "telegraf" # required

[[outputs.elasticsearch]]
   urls = [ "http://127.0.0.1:9200" ] # required.
   timeout = "5s"
   index_name = "telegraf-%Y.%m.%d" # required.
   manage_template = true
   template_name = "telegraf"
   overwrite_template = false

 [[outputs.file]]
   files = ["stdout", "/home/zeinab/metrics.out"]
   data_format = "influx"

[[inputs.cpu]]
  percpu = true
  totalcpu = true
  collect_cpu_time = false
  report_active = false

[[inputs.disk]]
  ignore_fs = ["tmpfs", "devtmpfs", "devfs"]

[[inputs.diskio]]

[[inputs.kernel]]

[[inputs.mem]]

[[inputs.processes]]

[[inputs.swap]]

[[inputs.system]]

[[inputs.jolokia2_agent]]
   urls = ["http://192.168.100.179:8778/jolokia"]
   [[inputs.jolokia2_agent.metric]]
      name = "heap_memory_usage"
      mbean  = "java.lang:type=Memory"
      paths = ["HeapMemoryUsage"]

  [[inputs.jolokia2_agent.metrics]]
       name = "send_success"
       mbean  = "wr-core:type=monitor,name=execution"
       paths = ["MessageSendSuccessCount"]
```

I start `telegraf` as a service:

```
service telegraf start
```

Comment: it may help if you show two things: 1) how you start it; 2) the whole config

Comment: @YuriG, would you please review my edit?

Comment: but you got influxdb output section there, that is as EXPLICIT as it can be - what's your problem, I don't get it at all now?

Comment: @YuriG, I expect to get output for all output sections I have mentioned. Right now, I get nothing for `outputs.file` section. I said nothing about `influx`. The error I have mentioned in the question is related to `outputs.file` section. BTW, I have removed excessive data; please review the question again.

Comment: Dear Zeinab. Unfortunatedly, you overlooked the fact that the history of your edits is available to anyone. And that makes the fact that you're simply LYING when you say " I said nothing about influx" VERY OBVIOUS.  Cause this is your words: "I should mention that I have no InfluxDB; I just want to write my output metrics into a file". And you'd changed the output sample too. Thus - I beg your pardon, but I'm not interested in helping you any more.

Comment: @YuriG, I think there is a little misunderstanding here. When I said "I said nothing about influx", I meant I didn't say that I have any problem with influx. I am currently trying to fix problem about saving in a file; then I was wondering if mentioning influx have led you away from the main problem, so I removed it. BTW, I don't think using the word **LYING** is an appropriate social behaviour in a professional web-site; you can ask. However, I really appreciate you trying to help.